# Why is my Nightmare test always successful even when it should fail?

Tags: testing, mocha.js

I wrote this test according to the tutorial I saw. I purposely want to get a failure (number of likes) but I always get a passing test.

This is my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test youtube search results', function() {

    it('check the likes', function() {
        var nightmare = Nightmare()
        nightmare
            .goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_oPsFTyhjY')
            .scrollTo(10000,0)
            .wait('#comment-section-renderer-items')
            .evaluate(function () {
                return document.querySelector('#watch8-sentiment-actions > span > span:nth-child(1) > button > span').innerText;
            })
            .end()
            .then(function(likes) {
                expect(likes).to.equal('245'); 
            })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get from Nightmare is a promise. Just return the promise from your test. And set a higher timeout to give time to Nightmare to run. So:

```
it('check the likes', function() {
    this.timeout(10000); // <-- Set a higher timeout.
    var nightmare = Nightmare()
    return nightmare                 // <-- The return is here.
        .goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_oPsFTyhjY')
        .scrollTo(10000,0)
        .wait('#comment-section-renderer-items')
        .evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector('#watch8-sentiment-actions > span > span:nth-child(1) > button > span').innerText;
        })
        .end()
        .then(function(likes) {
            expect(likes).to.equal('245'); 
        })
});
```

Otherwise, Mocha does not know when your test is actually done. For asynchronous tests, you must tell Mocha when the test is done. Returning a promise is one way to do this.

Comment: this is the error I got Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at null.<anonymous>

Comment: I don't use Nightmare. Probably, the issue is that it just takes too long for it to do its work before Mocha decides to timeout. I've modified my answer to also increase the timeout. You may need to use a higher number.

Comment: it weird,when I try to make a simple test like expect(2).to.equal(2) it works fine,but this code doesn't work.

Comment: It is still timing out or what?

Comment: yes the same,Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at null.<anonymous> ..

Comment: I don't understand what done() function,it asking me.

Comment: That error indicates you used a timeout of 1000. I specified a timeout of **10000** in my answer (And I said you may need to increase it. I don't know whether Nightmare needs 10 seconds or 12 or 15.)

Comment: Glad to help! I see you are a new user. The way the indicate appreciation on SO is to upvote answers (which you cannot do at your reputation level) and mark them as accepted (which you can do) by clicking on the check mark next to them. Upvoting and accepting is also useful to other readers to know that the answer is worth their time reading.

Comment: good to know! another weird problem. in youtube link it works fine, when I put vimeo it gives me error.
Error: .wait() timed out after 30000msec

Comment: That's a different problem so you should ask a new question. Make sure that you research it first (maybe there's already an answer somewhere) and provide all diagnostic information in your post. You should make it a [mcve]. That's the best way to get an answer quickly and avoid getting guess answers.